# How do I disable Tomcat request logging in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging, eclipse-wtp

It seems nowadays you need a PHD just to understand Tomcat logging...*sigh*. In one of my Eclipse/WTP projects Tomcat logs each request (before and after):

```
...
13.02.2012 20:50:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: After request [uri=/demo-webmvc-web/scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js?null]
13.02.2012 20:50:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Before request [uri=/demo-webmvc-web/images/logo.gif?null]
13.02.2012 20:50:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: After request [uri=/demo-webmvc-web/images/logo.gif?null]
...
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Is this being logged to a file or to the console? If it's the former, could you provide the path?

Comment: It's being logged to Eclipse console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that someone configured `org.springframework.web.filter.ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter` in `web.xml`. Since this filter invokes

```
filterConfig.getServletContext().log()
```

and since the Servlet context is of type `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext` it's this class that appears in the log message

```
13.02.2012 20:50:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log ...
```

This led me to believe logging was triggered by Tomcat itself.